# Cloning a git-svn repository leads to "disappearing" branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-svn, git-clone

**Foreword**

We have a big SVN repository (200k+ commits and hundreds of branches and tags). A big, ominous, unmaintainable, frustrating mess. To work more efficiently, about a year ago I did a git svn clone on my development machine, so I locally develop on GIT and then push to SVN.

We're now thinking about splitting up the repository and move the main development branches to git, or at least to move our development branch on git.

Since I have my local git repository, I wanted to do some test by cloning a part of it and push it to our company's GitLab, but without much success, probably because I lack the knowledge of some Git mechanisms

**Let's start**

In order to do some quick tests without pushing the entire 30GB repository, I wanted to do a shallow clone of my local Git repo and push the clone using the following command:

```
git clone --depth=1 --no-single-branch file:///path/to/repo
```

I wanted to clone the HEAD revision of every branch, but the clone included only the master branch and our development branch, nothing else (I'm not sure about the tags, I didn't check). After a while I realised that the clone included only our dev branch because it was the only one that I ever checked out (even though the git svn repository is a full clone of the SVN repository).

I then tried to do a

```
git clone file:///path/to/repo
```

and I again got only the master and my development branch, nothing else.

In these two attempts I noticed that the clone was much smaller (200-700MB) than the original git repository (30GB). In the second try I was expecting a repository of the same size of the original.

So I realised that git is cloning only the checked out branches, not the remote ones (remotes/svn/*). Why, since the git svn repo is a full copy of the svn repo? Why is it not cloning all the branches? They are there (otherwise the git svn repo wouldn't be so big), they just aren't checked out. And... How we can talk of "remote" branches? Aren't they part of the git svn repo, and should be considered local?

So how could I tell git to consider all those branches when cloning the git svn repo? I wouldn't like to to a massive checkout of all the branches in the git svn repo, it sounds to me like a clumsy and messy solution.

**Update**

Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry for not replying you sooner, but you left me quite a lot of documentation to read, plus I had to do some other research on my own!

So, if my understanding is correct, my git-svn repository contains all the commits of the original svn repository and it's aware that the svn repository contains branches and tags, but locally it doesn't have the association between the commit's SHA1 and the label which is the branch name, and I have to add those associations manually.

Your snippet is a very useful starting point, thanks!

I also discovered the magic argument `--mirror` for the clone command, which imported also the remotes, so I didn't have to touch the git-svn repo, but I later created the branches directly on the cloned git repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: you'll need to create actual branch names for each branch you want to have as a branch.  Remote-tracking names just don't count when cloning (well, usually).  This can be very cheap!  Read on for the long explanation.

Here's a cheap way to create local branches from each `refs/remotes/svn/*` name:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/remotes/svn |
    while read name; do
        local=${name#refs/remotes/svn/}  # remove the icky part from the name
        [ "$local" == HEAD ] && continue
        git branch $local $name
    done
```

This (note: untested, might have some minor bugs) will print an error message for those names that have corresponding local branch names; presumably you can ignore that.

> ... So I realised that git is cloning only the checked out branches, not the remote ones ...

There isn't really any such thing as a "remote branch".  Well, unless you define "remote branch" in such a way that there is.  Which ultimately leaves us with the problem of defining "branch" in the first place: see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  When being careful about this—as opposed to everyday conversation—I like to be sure to use the two-word phrase *branch name* to refer to names like `master`, which are actually already shortened: see below.

What Git deals with are *commits*, as found by *names*, and by other commits.  See [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) for a proper definition of *reachability* and a lot of the associated stuff,<sup>1</sup> but the general idea is that names—full names like `refs/heads/master` or `refs/remotes/svn/foo`—each hold the hash ID of one commit.  That one commit remembers which commit(s) come right before it.  Those commits—the *parent* commits—remember their predecessor commits, the grandparents remember *their* predecessors, and so on.

What `git clone` does is:

1. create a new empty directory (or use one you tell it to use);
2. create a new empty repository in that directory, with `git init`;
3. add a *remote*, which consists of a simple name like `origin` and a URL (and some configuration—this can be slipped to step 4, or considered part of step 3);
4. do any additional necessary configuration;
5. run `git fetch`; and last
6. run a `git checkout` on a name that either you supply, or the other Git supplies, or—worst fallback case—try to `git checkout master`.

Step 5 here is the most important one for you here, because `git fetch` is where all the main action is.

> Why is it not cloning all the branches?

When `git fetch` runs, it gets a listing from the *other* Git, in which the other Git tells it about *all* of its names.  The other Git will say, e.g., *I have `refs/heads/master`, that's commit `a123456...`; I have `refs/remotes/svn/foo`, that's commit `b789abc...`* and so on.

*Your* Git then *throws out* any name that does *not* start with `refs/heads/` or `refs/tags/`.  The resulting list of names are their Git's *branch names* and *tag names*.  All other names fall into other categories.  In particular, any name starting with `refs/remotes/` is a *remote-tracking name*,<sup>2</sup> so it gets thrown out.

Your Git then asks their Git for the commits (by hash ID) and any other objects needed to make the commits complete and useful.  Your Git also asks for objects identified via tag names, as long as you're taking the tags—though exactly which tags get taken when gets very complex depending on `git fetch` options.

Once your Git has the commit objects, and other internal objects if/as needed, your Git then copies their *branch* names—their `refs/heads/master` and the like—to *your* remote-tracking names.  Their `refs/heads/master` becomes your `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  Their `refs/heads/develop` (if one exists) becomes your `refs/remotes/origin/develop`.

All of this happens during the `git fetch` step (step 5).  Options like `--single-branch` or `--no-single-branch` affect which of their branch names are matched, but not the transformation from branch name to remote-tracking name.  The `--mirror` option *does* affect the transformation, eliminating it entirely, but has a sometimes-unwanted side effect of implying `--bare` as well.

The last step, the `git checkout` in step 6, has one very big side effect.  The new clone you just made has *no* branch names.<sup>3</sup>  So `git checkout master` or whatever other name is clearly doomed to fail, right?  But it doesn't fail.  Instead, Git makes use of a clever (?) trick:  *When you ask to check out a branch name that does not exist, Git looks at the **remote-tracking names** to see if there's one that would match up.*  If so, Git will *create* the (local) branch name using the commit hash ID stored in the corresponding remote-tracking name.

So this *creates* whichever branch you asked for—or in this case, since you didn't specify one, has the other Git tell your Git which branch name the other Git recommends.  (That's usually just `master` anyway.)  Step 6 is what creates that.

If you have tags in the `origin` repository, you will have some number of them—between zero and all—in the new clone too.  You can explicitly ask for tags later, or not, with a later `git fetch`.  You can explicitly ask *not* to have tags in your new clone at clone time.  Tags that you do have at this point are simply copied from those in the other repository.  The idea here is that—unlike branch names, which are totally private to each repository—the tag names will be shared across all repositories, spread by repository-joining, almost like some sort of virus.<sup>4</sup>

Since your source repository has mostly just remote-tracking names, rather than branches, your clone—shallow or not—omits those names *and* commits that are reachable only *from* those names.

---

<sup>1</sup>This differs quite a bit from SVN, in which there's a single central server that can simply number each revision sequentially.  Git literally *can't* rely on sequential numbering, because there may be separate clones that are sequentially-but-parallel-ly (apologies for the non-word here ) acquiring *different* commits.  That is, suppose clones A and B are identical and each have 500 commits.  Then Alice, who's working in clone A, creates commit #501.  Meanwhile Bob, working in clone B, creates commit #501.  The two commits are different—maybe on different branches—and they're both #501.  Sequential numbers cannot work here.

<sup>2</sup>Git calls this a *remote-tracking branch name*.  I used to use this phrase, but I now think the word *branch* in here is more misleading than useful.  You can call it what you want: just remember that it's not a *branch* name as those actually start with `refs/heads/`.

Note: Git usually strips off the `refs/heads/`, `refs/tags/`, and `refs/remotes/` parts here when printing the names, on the assumption that the output will still be clear enough.  Sometimes Git only strips off `refs/` though: try `git branch -r`, then try `git branch -a`.  (Why are these different?  It is a mystery.)

<sup>3</sup>If you used `--mirror`, your new clone has all the branch names, but then `git clone` *skips* step 6.  Your new clone is bare so there is no work-tree, and `git checkout` cannot be used.

<sup>4</sup>This is also how commits spread.  Suppose you have commits W, X, and Y in a row, that they don't have.  You connect to their Git as a `push` operation, and you give them all these three commits and ask them to set one of their names to remember commit `Y`, which remembers `X`, which remembers `W`, which remembers a commit they already have.

Or: they have these commits and you don't.  You connect to their Git as a `fetch` operation, they give you all three, and your Git sets your `origin/whatever` to remember commit `Y` now.

Basically, you get two Git repositories to mate.  One sends, the other receives.  The receiver gets all the new stuff that the receiver asks for that the sender sends, even if the receiver in the end didn't really want it after all:  at this point, the receiver can reject the request to update some *name* to remember the *last* commit in a chain of commits.  The receiver thereby keeps their old name and its old hash ID, or has no name (and no hash ID).

A commit or other Git object whose hash ID has no way to find it is eventually garbage-collected and tossed out.  For bare repositories this tends to be faster, and since Git 2.11, the server "receive commits and other Git objects" process sticks them in a quarantine area first, before decide that they're good and accepting them, or deciding that they're bad and rejecting them.  The accepted ones then migrate from quarantine to the real repository database, with the rejected ones being tossed quickly.  Pre-2.11 the received objects went in right away, temporarily bloating servers that, e.g., reject large files (think of GitHub's 100MB file size limits).

Shallow clones modify (some of) these rules: with a shallow clone, the receiving Git has a special file full of hash IDs.  It lacks those actual commits, but *pretends* that it has them, so that when the sender asks "do you have commit X" the answer is "yes", so that the sender then never sends commit X.

Comment: Thanks! I direcetly added an update to my original question with the answer!