# Why can i not create a master branch?

Tags: git, git-svn

Can someone please explain what i am doing wrong here?

```
$ git --version
git version 2.18.2

$ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

$ git branch
* (HEAD detached at origin/trunk)

$ git branch -m master
fatal: Invalid branch name: 'HEAD'
```

some context: this repo was created using `git svn` and i want to rename the `origin/trunk` branch to `master`.

```
$ git branch -a
* (HEAD detached at origin/trunk)
  remotes/origin/svn-branch1
  remotes/origin/svn-branch2
  ...
```

Comment: Is it that thing to do with GitHub renaming `master` to `main`? Try `git checkout main`

Comment: You don’t have any branches it seems. Create one with `git branch <name>` or in your case better `git checkout -b <name>`.

Comment: no, i have tons of branches, just not one called 'master' (this repo was imported using `git svn`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new branch based on current branch to work on a new feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706821/create-new-branch-based-on-current-branch-to-work-on-a-new-feature)

Comment: Ah, that's vital information.

Comment: no, i don't want to create a new branch, i want to rename the existing one. i think the quoted commands indicate that.

Comment: What command did you use to invoke `git-svn`? What is the output of `git branch -a`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635202/cloning-a-git-svn-repository-leads-to-disappearing-branches

Comment: @DBedrenko That's not consistent with the information displayed here, so it appears to be entirely unrelated.

Comment: Yes you *do* want to create a new branch, you just don’t know it yet :) In Git, "branch" does not exactly mean the same as in SVN, it’s just a movable reference to a commit.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

Use:

```
git checkout -b master origin/trunk
```

followed by whatever you will do to copy this Git repository elsewhere.  Feel free to delete the remote-tracking name `origin/trunk` *if* you're not going to do any further SVN imports:

```
git branch -d -r origin/trunk
```

You can repeat this for each SVN branch name, if you like.

#### Long

Some things you need to know:

1. You don't have *any* branches,<sup>1</sup> at the moment:

   > ```
   > $ git branch
   > * (HEAD detached at origin/trunk)
   > ```
2. You *do* have some *remote-tracking names* (Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, but they are not *branch names*, so I like to omit the word *branch* here).  Your SVN import created these:

   > ```
   > $ git branch -a
   > * (HEAD detached at origin/trunk)
   >   remotes/origin/svn-branch1
   >   remotes/origin/svn-branch2
   > ```

The first line is of course a repeat, but it indicates that there is a `remotes/origin/trunk`.  The extra word `remotes` here is from the fact that the *full* names of each of these is `refs/remotes/origin/name`; Git normally omits both `refs/` and `remotes/`, except for `git branch -a` which only omits `refs/` on the remote-tracking names (for no apparent reason).

Now, `git checkout` won't automatically create a (local) branch name unless there's one matching remote-tracking name.  Your SVN import did not create an `origin/master`, though it did create an `origin/trunk`.

Normally, remote-tracking names exist in your Git repository because of *branch* names that existed in some other Git repository.  If that were the case, you'd need to rename those branches in the other Git repository.  But in your case, there is no other Git repository (yet)—there is only an SVN repository.  In the SVN repository, there was a name `trunk` and your conversion copied that name here.

What you need to do is create the local branch name `master`.  The simplest command is `git checkout -b master starting-point`, as that will also put you *on* that branch (which you likely want).  The starting point is the commit to which you want this new name `master` to refer.

---

<sup>1</sup>In this context, the word *branch* means *branch name*.  In other contexts in Git, it means other things.  Git branches do not correspond very well to SVN branches.  See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), The error message will be clearer:

```
cannot rename the current branch while not on any
```

See [commit 77e7267](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77e7267e47aac247244dc4fb3538baff7463261f) (26 Oct 2022) by [Rubén Justo (`rjusto`)](https://github.com/rjusto).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit 0c02561](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c025612d4f53c0802d931fa75619d9494755ffb), 30 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77e7267e47aac247244dc4fb3538baff7463261f): error copying or renaming a detached HEAD
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Rubén Justo</sup>

> In [c847f53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c847f537125ceab3425205721fdaaa834e6d8a83) ("Detached HEAD (experimental)", 2007-01-01, Git v1.5.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c388761c153bc3e874e75f69ff77430164c038c4)) an error condition was introduced in `rename_branch()` to prevent renaming, later also copying, a detached HEAD.
>
> The condition used was checking for `NULL` in `oldname`, the source branch to rename/copy.
> That condition cannot be satisfied because if no source branch is specified, HEAD is going to be used in the call.
>
> The error issued instead is:
>
> ```
> fatal: Invalid branch name: 'HEAD'
> ```
>
> Let's remove the condition in `copy_or_rename_branch()` (the current function name) and check for HEAD before calling it, dying with the original intended error if we're in a detached HEAD.